# Getting a DNS SERVFAIL status for a domain registered in Route 53

Tags: dns, aws-route53

I recently purchased a domain from Route 53. At present it has a zone with just the NS and SOA records. I get a DNS SERVFAIL when I try to look it up:

```
% dig drpowellrecommends.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> drpowellrecommends.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 38825
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

I have tried deleting and recreating the zone but still getting the SERVFAIL. And any attempt to add A and CNAME records doesn't make the domain accessible on the Internet.

(The flags just mean 'query', 'recursion desired', 'recursion available', and are identical for a successful lookup of another domain.)

The domain looks healthy enough using whois or lookup.icann.org.

The only odd thing I can think that might be behind this is: I initially registered the domain using the anonymous email offered by Route53, but then, because I couldn't see the validation email, I changed that to an explicit email address I own and validated using that email address. But it's just a guess that that is related to the problem.

The Route53 zone does not have any DNSSEC keys, nor anything unusual. It's just minimal, plain vanilla.

Any ideas, beautiful people?